# Draw a picture of the images of vertical lines under the sine function. Do the same for the tangent function.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Draw a picture of the images of vertical lines under the sine function. Do the same for the tangent function.

The vertical line can be written as $$z=a+iy$$
So $$\sin(z)=\sin(a+iy)=\sin a \cos(iy)+\cos a\sin(iy)=\sin a \cosh y+i \cos a\sinh y$$
But I am not sure how to draw the pictures...Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both $\cos a$ and $\sin a$ are not $0$, then what you get are those points $x+yi$ such $\left(\frac x{\sin a}\right)^2-\left(\frac y{\cos a}\right)^2=1$. This is a branch of a hyperbola. If $\cos a=0$, you get just a vertical ray. And if $\sin a=0$, what you get a horizontal straight line.

In the case of the tangent function, you can use the same approach:\begin{align}\tan(a+iy)&=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(iy)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(iy)}\\&=\frac{\tan(a)+i\tanh(y)}{1-i\tan(a)\tanh(y)}\\&=\frac{\tan(a)-\tan^2(a)\tanh(y)}{1+\tan^2(a)\tanh^2(y)}+i\frac{\bigl(1+\tan^2(a)\bigr)\tanh(y)}{1+\tan^2(a)\tanh^2(y)}\end{align}Remember that the range of $\tanh$ is $(-1,1)$. What this is is:

- a line segment if $\tan(a)=0$;
- an arc of an ellipsis otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, but when $\cos a=0, \sin z$ only has the real part, is that should be a vertical line? Same thing for $\sin a =0$.

Comment: @Nan I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give me more hint for $\tan z$? Since I can' get a neat formula for $\tan z$ as for $\sin z$...Thanks~

Comment: @Nan You just do the same thing, using the formula$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(y)}.$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and I got $$\tan z=\frac{\tan x \ sech^2 y+i\tanh y \sec^2 x}{1+\tan^2x\tanh^2 y}$$

Comment: Hi, sorry for bothering... I saw you replied my another question. Could you tell me more about this one for $\tan$ case? Thank you!

Comment: @Nan I've edited my answer.